# Django Admin: Add foreign keys at same time as model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am a novice in Django and I'm learning the ropes of the admin interface. I have a model with several foreign keys. These foreign keys then reference other foreign keys. On the admin website after I register the Property model and then try to add it I am given a dropdown box for each foreign key model. However this dropdown box only lists existing foreign keys. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5LCu.png)

What would be great is if instead of a dropdown box there were extra fields so I could add the foreign key models as I add the property model. That way I wouldn't have to manually add foreign keys and then go back and add some more, and then go back and finally add the property data.

How can I do this? This feels like a simple enough question but after intense Googling I still can't find the answer, so I apologize in advance.

Example of two of my models:

```
  class Address(models.Model):
      state = models.ForeignKey('State')
      address1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      address2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=200)


 class Property(models.Model):
     address = models.ForeignKey('Address', blank=True, null=True)
     borrower = models.ForeignKey('Person', blank=True, null=True)
     company = models.ForeignKey('Company', blank=True, null=True)
     contract = models.ForeignKey('Contract', blank=True, null=True)
     loan_balance = models.IntegerField()
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     primary_email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     primary_phone = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     property_no = models.IntegerField()
```

Example of my admin.py:

```
  # Register your models here.

  class PropertyAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
      model = Property

  class PersonAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
      model = Person

  class CompanyAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
      model = Company

  class ContractAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
      model = Contract

  class CompletePropertyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      inlines = [PropertyAdmin, PersonAdmin, CompanyAdmin, ContractAdmin]   

  admin.site.register(Property)
```

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.8,

Guys, I'm not trying to be ambiguous. I just want to be able to add data to my foreign key models at the same time as I add data to the models that point to them.

In the picture I attached, instead of a dropdown box to select an existing Address, I want the fields of Address to be displayed (state, address1, address2, etc) so that I can fill out and add the address model at the same time as the property model. This should apply to all foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to the problem can be, to create a custom form with fields from both the models and at the time of saving the values, first create the instance of Address model and then with that instance save your final Property model.